# Moving html element towards mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html element: `<img src="./pic/char.png" width="30" height="30" alt="me">`
How would I constantly move this html element towards the cursor using javascript? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use a `mousemove` event handler to store the latest cursor position, and then update the image's position at regular intervals via the [`setInterval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675038/attemping-to-get-a-div-to-follow-cursor-on-mousemove-but-with-a-delay/

Comment: You have to try something, then you can ask a question if it doesn't work. Please don't just ask for others to write code for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi refer this http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/440/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="moveAble">
    <div class="info"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1498221863/Jodis_Gifts_logo_hi_res_normal.jpg" alt="info" /></div>
    </div

>
```

and **JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var $moveable = $('.moveAble');
      $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          $moveable.css({'top': e.pageY,'left': e.pageX});
      });
    });
```

Comment: I would do it like you did. +1

Answer (score 0):

Since your code can get more complicated in the future, e.g. it may add text etc. in addition to the image, I would just use a ready made library, qtip2.

```
$(element).qtip({
    content: { your content/image here },
    position: { target: mouse }
});
```